# How could i calculate the sparsity of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sparse-matrix

i have a data.frame structured like this:

```
  A B C D E
F 1 0 7 0 0
G 0 0 0 1 1
H 1 1 0 0 0
I 1 2 1 0 0
L 1 0 0 0 0
```

and i want to calculate the sparsity(i.e. the percentage of 0 values) of this data.frame.
How could i do?

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(df == 0)/(dim(df)[1]*dim(df)[2])
[1] 0.6
```

Comment: Or use `prod(dim(df))` in de denominator